# Why isn't this a contradiction? (Preimage of an open set)

Tags: continuity

My question arises from the combination of both following theorems:

> **Theorem 1:** Every open set is a continuous image of a closed set. That is, for every open set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ there is a closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  and a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f\left( C \right) = A$
>
> **Theorem 2:** A function is continuous iff it's preimage on every open set is open. That is, $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continious iff $f^{-1}\left( A \right)$ is open for every open set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set. From Theorem 1 we know that there is a closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  and a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f\left( C \right) = A$ .

We now have a continuous function $f$ and an open set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ ,  so  by Theorem 2 it's preimage $f^{-1}\left( A \right)$ has to be open. But $f^{-1}\left( A \right)=C$ is a closed set.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because $f(C)=A$ does not mean that $f^{-1}(A) = C$.  You only conclude that $f^{-1}(A) \supset C$, but the preimage could be larger.

Comment: So take $f\left|_{C}\right.$

Comment: But then $C$ *is* both open and closed in $C$, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by both open and closed in $C$?

Comment: And how you conclude that $C \subset f^{-1}\left( A \right)$?

Comment: If you restrict the function to $C$, then you have to restrict your open and closed sets to their intersection with $C$ (the subspace topology) for theorems 1 and 2 to remain valid. A set is "open in $C$" if it is the intersection of $C$ with an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (similar definition for "closed in $C$").

Comment: That's just the definition of $f^{-1}$ ...

Comment: I mean how you conclude that $C\subsetneq f^{-1}\left(A\right)$?

Comment: First, note that just because you conclude that $C$ is both open and closed, that is *not* immediately a contradiction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set). But if $C$ is not clopen, then you do get a contradiction and therefore we must have $C \subsetneq f^{-1}(A)$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the only clopen sets are the empty set and the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^n$.